# Nativescript Provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, nativescript

We have just updated our provisioning profile on our Apple developer account. When using the build command: -

ns build ios --release --for-device --provision

The available provisioning profiles are listed under our Team ID but neither reflect the date of provisioning profiles online.

[image]

[image]

The First screenshot shows the date on the developer portal as 2022/03/22
The second screenshot is the response to the build command above showing 3 Mar 2021

Any idea why the build is not picking up the new dated provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per my last comment:

Not sure what was going on, but ran the build with --provision today and got the updated provisioning profile with the correct date. Built the app and checked the expiry date and it now matches the provisioning profile. Maybe Apple were having issues

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a mismatch with the certificate those profiles were signed with.
I'd say you start over with emitting a new cert, upload it to your account and use it to sign a new profile.

Comment: The certificate we use is valid until the end of March 2022.

Comment: Meant to say that previously updating the provisioning profile was all that was required.

Comment: I didn't say it was not valid.
Same thing happened to me recently and I solved it as described in my post.

Comment: Not sure what was going on, but ran the build with --provision today and got the updated provisioning profile with the correct date. Built the app and checked the expiry date and it now matches the provisioning profile. Maybe Apple were having issues.